# Unable to use app.patch and getting an error Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Tags: mongodb, express

I am trying to use app.patch to modify the values in an array in my collection but when i use patch in postman i get this error -Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client.

```
app.patch('/specialities/patch/:id',(req,res)=> {
    var updateObject = req.body; 
    var id = req.params.id;
    HospitalSpeciality.update({placeid  : id}, {$set: updateObject},function(e, results) {
        res.json(results)
    });
    res.send('temperory');
})
```

**Schema**

```
const hospitalspecialityschema = new Schema({
    placeid: String,
    specialities:{
        type:Array,
        default:''
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to send a response twice from `res.json(results);` and `res.send('temperory');`

Remove either one of them and it should fix it.